# Getting simple Json string from url and converting it to String[] Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to pull Json string from url and put it into `String[]` inside my android application.

String i am getting from my url is `"[\"What is your name?\",\"How do you do?\"]"`

I am trying to create `Quizz` class in my app where i want to call constructor and then it pull data from url and put it into private variables.

I have tried many things but getting multiple errors (with network and other stuff) and now i am somewhere with async tasks where i got lost and think i am going totally wrong way.

Class i want to have is like this:

```
public class Quizz {
    private String[] Questions;

    public Quizz() {
        // Here i want to load data from url into variable Questions
    }

    public String getQuestion(int id) {
        return "Not implemented!";
    }
}
```

And when i create `Quizz` object in my main activity i want to have questions loaded.

Comment: I'd recommend the android https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader but that doesn't look like JSON - should be key-value pairs.  Anyways, rectify that and using asynctask to perform on background thread.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following article to help you decode your json
[Article Link](https://medium.com/@hissain.khan/parsing-with-google-gson-library-in-android-kotlin-7920e26f5520)
Also, You can use JSONArray in the Following [Article](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/org/json/JSONArray)

Comment: There is nowhere explained how i get string from my url

Comment: Can you provide url sample?

Comment: That is json i print from going to `somewebsite.com/getJsonString`

Answer (score 0):

Use Retrofit to Connect to API, and Use its converter to deserialize the JSON Response.

https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial

it's very effective and has error handling built into it.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are looking for a string[] array but in this case its best to use a arraylist as sizes can change when retrieving the response.

```
//create empty strings arraylist
List<String> strings = new Arraylist<>()
//try parse the response as a JSONarray object
try{
    //get url string response as a json array
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) urlStringResponse;
    //parse through json array and add to list
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        String str = (String) jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        strings.add(str);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON", "Problem parsing the JSON results", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about to use [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method?

```
val string = "[\"What is your name?\",\"How do you do?\"]"
val split: List<String> = string.subSequence(1, string.length - 1).split(',')
val array = split.toTypedArray()

array.forEach { println(it) }
```

And result will be

```
"What is your name?"
"How do you do?"
```